# How can I convert a extremly big .dat file to Image files?(Like jpg or something)

Tags: image, image-processing

I have a folder of image file which have been compressed into .dat file. Since the .dat files are extremly huge(They are the microscopic image of the organ.), I don't really know what kind of tools that I can use to convert it into jpeg file. So the best case would that the whole image is split up into pieces, and I can get all the pieces of the image.

Answer (score 1):

The ".dat" file suffix is used broadly, so you'll need to specify more details on what format/source software created the original data.  As a guess, from a quick search of ".dat" format microscopy, these tools looks like they might be applicable to your domain:

http://gwyddion.net/

or

http://www.openmicroscopy.org/site/products/bio-formats

If you can't find a library for the format/languages you are using, then you'll need to find documentation of the file format, and write a converter (at least, the reading portion of the converter - you can use something like libjpeg to handle the writing portion.)

Comment: @Yaxuan-Yu can test out whether Bio-Formats will read her files by downloading FIJI: http://fiji.sc/Fiji - "Bio-Formats is largely integrated with the File/Open command of Fiji"